# Changing Text in WebPage with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, php, html, google-chrome-console

I have a problem with updating html element with javascript code. I'm trying to update html text input on google chrome console. For ex. cpuboss . com here is some html code from cpuboss

```
<input placeholder="find a cpu" name="query" type="text" id="product-lookup" autocomplete="off" class="">
```

I tried almost all code examples i found on stackoverflow but i couldn't update the text element.

```
document.getElementsByName('query').value = "test"
```

I tried .value .innerhtml .attribute etc. etc. but they doesn't work. Can someone help me why these codes not working ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`document.getElementsByName` returns a `NodeList`, basically an array. You're gonna want the first one, like so:

```
document.getElementsByName('query')[0].value = "test";
```

Comment: You should add to suggest using the id since id must be unique, and he can just reference it direct: `document.getElementById('product-lookup').value = "test";`

Comment: @zevee  I didn't know that. Thank you soo much it's worked.
IncredibleHat Thanks for the tip! Some elements doesn't have id value so i will use it when available.